# Python list for loop and Boolean value

Tags: python, loops, boolean

I have couple of questions. I have tried my best to come up with an output and I am close but not exactly correct. So, I would appreciate your help.

**Q1:**

```
found = False
print('Before', found)
for value in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15] : 
   if value == 3 :
       found = True
   print(found, value)
print('After', found)
```

Output:
Before False
False 9
False 41
False 12
True 3
True 74
True 15
After True

So, above is my output and I want to make it True only when the value is 3 but it is coming True for 74 and 15 as well. How can I edit the code so that it should return False for 74 and 15? Please help.

Comment: You don't need `found` at all. You don't even need an `if`. Just do `print(value == 3, value)`

Comment: Q2: Move the `print` to be *after* the loop, not *in* the loop. Q3: Get rid of the loop and just to `print(min(l))`.

Comment: @deceze can you please write it over here? Will appreciate it.

Comment: - - - - and Q2?

Answer (score 0):

```py
found = False
print('Before', found)
for value in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15] : 
   if value == 3 :
       found = True

       ##### use else ####
   else:
       found = False
   print(found, value)
print('After', found)
```

or

```py
found = False
print('Before', found)
for value in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15] :
    value = (i == 3)
    print(found, value)
print('After', found)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
found = False
print('Before', found)
for value in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15] : 
   if value == 3 :
       found = True
   else:
        found=False
   print(found, value)
print('After', found)
```

This is why it returns true on 74 and 75:When the "found" variable is reached to 3 in the loop, it returns true for the remaining elements since the variable "found" is "true" once.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an else statement as:

```py
else:
       found = False
```

you are getting the error because once the value of found is changed after 3 as True
there is no code to change its value back to False.